# error while restoring database from mysql: ERROR 1006 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, restore, mysqldump, errors

I made a mysqldump from all my databases prior to fully deinstall and reinstall MariaDB. while restoring the databases with the following command, logged in as root:

```
MySQL -u root -p < /mnt/backups/190612alldb.sql
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1006 (HY000) at line 22: Can't create database 'mydatabase'
>   (errno: 2 "No such file or directory")

'mydatabase' is just one of several databases I previously dumped. when this error occurs none of the databases is restored.

what's going on here?

Comment: *ERROR 1006 (HY000) at line 22* Show this "line 22" in your question.

Comment: i'd love to, but i don't understand which file i should go through...

Comment: *i don't understand which file i should go through... * The file which is piped into mysql. `/mnt/backups/190612alldb.sql` in shown command line.

Comment: Please run `ls -l /mnt/backup/*.sql | grep -c 190612alldb`. If `0` comes back, the file is not in that folder. If `1` comes back, then the file is there. What number comes back ???

Comment: *What number comes back ???* file is there, it's 1